# Set Scrollviewer position of GridView control

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, winrt-xaml

I'm developing a Windows Universal App, I have this GridView in Xaml:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1"  Height="700" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Name="GridPoints" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <GridView x:Name="GridViewList"  ItemsSource="{Binding Points}" ItemClick="GridView_ItemClick"  IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                       ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
                      ItemContainerStyle="{Binding Source={StaticResource GridViewItemContainer}}" SelectedItem="{Binding SlectedPoint, Mode=TwoWay}"  >
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>...etc...
```

I need to change the position of the scrollviewer to show focus on my selected point presents in the list of binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for:

```
ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(double);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltoverticaloffset(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks it works! There is  also the ScrollIntoView(Item) that works fine.